# Upload file in binary mode using Orion SSH2

Tags: java, sftp

Does someone know how to upload a file using binary transfer mode using Orion SSH (a Java library, formerly Ganymed SSH)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Binary mode is default for SFTP. ASCII mode appeared only in SFTP version 4, so most likely you are already using binary mode for file transfer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought I had to set the transfer mode similar to the way it is donde with ftp protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene; this website is very helpful.